# Next focus down issue about pointer in the edit text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

There are some `TextView` and `EditText` in my app's form UI to update user's information and all of them in the separate linear layouts like below.

My problem is, I am using `android:nextFocusDown` focusing to the next `EditText` but when user tab to the next button in the keyboard, `EditText` focuses the correct field but not the pointer. It is at the beginning of the field not the end of it. How can I get the pointer to the end of the field in the XML without programmatically?

**Part of the xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/formLayout"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<TextView
    android:text="PROFILE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/topLayout"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"/>

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="FIRST NAME: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtFNameLabel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtFNameLabel"
        android:id="@+id/txtFName"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtFNameLabel"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <TextView
        android:text="LAST NAME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtLNameLabel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <EditText
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtLName"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this way**

In place of `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtLName"` use `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` it will focus on next input field and pointer also.

Comment: remove these three from everywhere  android:focusable="true", 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true", android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

Comment: put java file too, something in java.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

maybe the closest thing you can get. But I think without writing code it's not possible for now

Comment: So, the reason for the issue is because of the edit texts in the separate linear layouts?